# Можно ли переставить ssd на другой ноут

Tags: windows, память, hdd, ssd, ноутбук

Суть такова, есть два ноутбука. 1 - мой, 2 - не мой, но я им пользуюсь, и на нём хард повреждённый. Хочу переставлять ssd из моего ноута туда-сюда, по мере использования, потому что второй попросту мощнее, но к нему нет доступа 24/7. Винда на ссд стоит 11я, она сможет подтягивать необходимые драйвера при перестановки ssd из системы в систему?

Comment: да, но не факт что без приключений. Смотря как ставилась винда, смотря какие настройки в биосе. Пробуй да делай. По мере проблем уже задавай вопросы) Возможно сразу все получится без проблем, а возможно столкнешься с каким-то говном)

Comment: @Gelloiss винда 11 ставилась с обходом tpm на старенький hp с AMD A серией процов, и r7 графикой, а ставить собираюсь на acer nitro 5 с r560 и ryzen 5, чую отладить этот процесс будет не самой лёгкой задачей)